# Digital Ocean Load balancer traffic mirroring

Tags: load-balancing, digital-ocean

Think about a scenario . I have a Digital Ocean Loadbalancer and have multiple application server inside of it . I want to request mirror all of my traffic to the spesific machine . But if i put that machine behind the load balancer it does not take all of the traffic . I need all of the traffic for spesific reasons. How can i do that ?